# How to change a RestController to MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I created an app using Spring and RestControllers. Now I would like to recreate the exact same controllers but using MVC controllers instead of Rest ones.

Is it just an annotation to change like going from `@RestController` to `@Controller`?

Is there something else to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RestController` is an annotation with `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller`. If you want to return some data structure like JSON, you should use `@ResponseBody` in controller method and  @Controller in controller class. You can also only use `@RestController` in controller class. If you want to return page like *jsp* or *html*, you should use `@Controller` and `InternalResourceViewResolver`.